# ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key after pandas update

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error after upgrading to pandas 1.2.0:

`ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`

This is my "semplified" code:
 `data_final = data.loc[data.groupby(by=["field1", "field2"], as_index=False)["field5"].idxmin()][['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']]`

This code was working fine before upgrading to pandas 1.2.0

What's wrong now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create default unique index and then remove `]` after `idxmin` and `as_index=False`:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
cols = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']
data_final = data.loc[data.groupby(by=["field1", "field2"])["field5"].idxmin(), cols]
```

Comment: now i get this error:   `KeyError: "None of [Index(['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]` . Your previous answer ( before  you edited) got me no errors  `data_final = data.loc[data.groupby(by=["field1"])["field5"].idxmin()][['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4','field5']]`

Comment: @Mark - what is `print (data.columns)` ? Error means there not exist this columns names.

Comment: Your edited code works if i replace `cols = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']` instead of `cols = [['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']]`